# Unable to mount windows share in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, smbfs

I am trying to mount windows machine directory in my ubuntu 10.04.3 server. When I try to see the shared directory in the windows server its showing properly using the below command. The windows mahcine is joined to local domain xyz.com

My doubt is, cant we mount the shared directory which is connected to local domain server?
I am getting this error in both smbfs / cifs.

```
 smbclient -L //192.168.39.152/ -U svnbackup

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
    Android         Disk
    C$              Disk      Default share
    CENTOS          Disk
    E$              Disk      Default share
    G$              Disk      Default share
    IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
    Nagios          Disk
    test            Disk
```

When I try to mount the test directory using below command Its show error saying permission denied as below.

```
  mount.smbfs //192.168.39.152/test /mnt/smbfs -o username=username,password=Svn1234,domain=xyz.com
  mount error(13): Permission denied Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: I hope that's not your *actual* password there.  There's also a discrepancy between the IP address at the top of your question and the IP address at the bottom.

Comment: Even I created a local user & tested, In that also I am facing same issue.

Oh!! thats a typo error

Comment: It might be bugs with the kernel, try  to upgrade the kernel and check it

Comment: Upgraded to 2.6.32-39

Comment: Can you confirm what user you're running the mount command as and that the `/mnt/smbfs` has the correct permissions. You need root permissions to mount filesystems unless the correct options are specified in `/etc/fstab` (`user`).

Comment: I'm running the below command as root user.

root@ubuntu:~# mount -t cifs //192.168.39.152/test -o username=svnbackup,password=Svn1234,domain=xys.com /mnt/cifs/

Directory Permission :
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 48 2012-03-06 18:16 smbfs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
mount -t cifs //address/sharename /mnt/whatever \
-o `**username=DomainName/username**,password=password`
```

if it doesnt work, try:

```
mount.cifs //address/Share /mnt/share/ -o username=address/username
```

dont add a password, it should prompt u for one and possible it'll work, gl

Comment: Thanks buddy, mount -t cifs //address/sharename /mnt/whatever -o username=DomainName/username,password=password

This worked :-) Saved my life.

Comment: glad i could help :)

Comment: That worked! But I am trying to access a folder which is publicly shared and not password protected. But it still asks for password. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I've found solution on this site: [Issue Mounting CIFS Share | ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1634635)

Generally in Windows you should add this key in regedit. It works for me now.
Key goes in:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System**

Key DWORD (32-bit): **LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy**
Key Value : 1

Comment: Note that this applies only starting with Vista, it has no effect on XP.

Comment: Can set via PowerShell: `Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ -Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -Value 1`

Comment: Do you need to restart the OS after the insert?, I tried with my Windows Server 2012 R2 but I still have the error (13).

Comment: I just used this info to resolve the same issue trying to connect to the hidden admin shares on my Windows 10 laptop from an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VirtualBox Guest VM. I did not have to restart either OS after creating the registry entry.

Comment: Or use the simpler `reg.exe`. Paste this into an admin command prompt : `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try cifs. smbfs is deprecated by cifs-utils. smbfs is used in Debian <= 3.

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.39.152/test -o \
  username=username,password=Svn1234,domain=xyz.com /mnt/smbfs
```

Comment: mount -t cifs //192.168.39.152/test -o username=username,password=Svn1234,domain=xys.com /mnt/smbfs/
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)