# How to mount a windows administrative share on linux via SMB

Tags: windows, samba, network-share, mount, cifs

I'm currently trying to mount a windows shared drive under linux.
The machine is using windows 7 and by default it shares all windows drives if you login as an administrator. I've been able to login and list/copy/delete files via my android phone but I'm having a problem with mounting it on a server.

The command I'm trying:
`mount -t smbfs -o username=MyUsername //10.0.0.2/$D /mnt/machine_1_d`

I think the problem comes from the `$` sign in `$D`. I just can't remember what was the fix for this. I'm sure it was something really simple but I can't find it on the net also.

Comment: I think it should work if you just write the visible name instead of `$D`.

Comment: The name of the shared folder is `$D` (if that's what you meant) :)

Comment: tftd, You might want to change the name of the question to "How to mount a windows administrative share on linux via samba" for the next guy to find it.

Comment: Don't admin shares (for drive letters) have the dollar after the letter? e.g. `D$` ... Just seen your comment on another answer - perhaps you should state yours are a different way around ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try escaping the $ character with a \

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=MyUsername //10.0.0.2/D\$ /mnt/machine_1_d
```

Comment: Also it appears you can do it like this `mount -t smbfs -o username=MyUsername "//10.0.0.2/$D" /mnt/machine_1_d`. This also appears to be working properly. Thanks!

Comment: @tftd I assume you meant `'//10.0.0.2/$D'` (with single quotes). Otherwise bash would resolve `$D` to an empty string. In other words, `"//10.0.0.2/$D"` would resolve to `"//10.0.0.2/"`, unless you happened to have an environment variable called `D`.

Answer (score 5):

Administrative shares in Windows are named with the volume letter first, then the '$' symbol, not the other way around.

C: --> C$

D: --> D$

```
sudo mount -t smbfs -o username=graeme,domain=example //server.example.com/C$ /mnt/bla
```

Comment: Yes that's correct. In my case, though, it's the other way around. I don't know why. I guess the admin has done some custom settings or something...

Answer (score 5):

My issue was related to:
"mount error(13): Permission denied Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)"
For me the solution was adding key to regedit in Window. Below is my answer in other topic:
https://serverfault.com/a/619963/237340

Comment: This was also my issue. I was so close to getting to my laptop Windows share from servers at work. Another day....

Comment: Can set via PowerShell: `Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ -Name LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy -Value 1`

Answer (score 0):

I would add a line for that purpose to */etc/fstab* file:

```
//10.0.0.2/d$/ /mnt/documents cifs noserverino,rw,iocharset=utf8,password=xxxxxxxxxx,username=user_with_administrative_rights,domain=my_windows_domain 0 0
```

After saving changes to this file, mount the file system by means of the command `mount -a`.

In this case the option *rw* allows the directory to be read-write, otherwise it should have the option *ro*.

Answer (score 0):

To enable access to administrative shares you may also need to "[disable UAC remote restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/user-account-control-and-remote-restriction#how-to-disable-uac-remote-restrictions)". This can be done with the `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` registry key:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\ /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```